# How to detect if document back to focus?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, settimeout, jquery-events

I'm using html5 document object with hidden attribute to detect if user has switched to another tab. How do I check if user has returned to the current tab in the same way?

Please refer my code:

```
var PERIOD_NOT_VISIBLE = 60000;
var PERIOD_VISIBLE = 5000;              
var timestring = 0;

(function callThis(timestring) {

    //update notification

    timer = setTimeout(function() {

    callThis(timestring);                
    }, (document.hidden) ? PERIOD_NOT_VISIBLE : PERIOD_VISIBLE);

})();
```

Interval is made at every 5 seconds to update notification. When current document loses focus, the interval timer is increased to 1 min. So this latest request will only run after 1 min.

If the user returns to the document anytime before the 1 minute completed, he still not updated with the notification as he has to wait for the current request to complete first. Only after that the timer back to 5 seconds.

Is it possible to detect if user has back to current document without waiting for request complete after 1 min?

Comment: You do this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Answer (score 4):

You can use `blur` and `focus` event in window to detect it.

```
$(window).on("blur", function() {
   // do whatever you want
    $("body").append("<p>Windows lost focus</p>");
});
$(window).on("focus", function() {
   // do whatever you want
    $("body").append("<p>Windows got focus</p>");
});
```

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/uX84X/9/ (Click in result box of jsfiddle to test)