# Show a white page (i.e nothing at all) in case of user inactivity, and refresh the page on selecting the tab in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

P.S- In contrast to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502392/how-to-detect-if-document-back-to-focus), my problem is to check if a user is inactive, irrespective of whether s/he has switched tab or not.

I want to show a blank page when the user is inactive for some time, and has switched tab. But, as soon as the user opens the tab, the page should refresh and all the contents should appear.

The inactivity time is **15 minutes**.

Here is my Jacascript code, but it does only half the task. I dont know how to do the ther half

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
     $(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
         time = new Date().getTime();
     });

     function refresh() {
         if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 60000) 
             window.location.reload(true);
         else 
             setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
     }

     setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
```

Comment: Just add `display:none` to the style of `body` to make a white page.

Comment: *but it does only half the task* - which half does it do?  Seems to *reload* the page after a minute.   You could also use `debounce` and clear the timers.

Comment: Does this answer (part of) your question? [How to detect if document back to focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502392/how-to-detect-if-document-back-to-focus)

Comment: @freedomn-m The question link that you referred to, DOES NOT answer mine

Comment: *irrespective of whether s/he has switched tab or not* - you seem to be asking multiple questions but dressing them up as one.   1) blank page after 15 mins of inactivity   2) refresh when?  If not when they switch tab then why does half your question talk about "*and has switched tab*" / "*on selecting the tab*" / "*as soon as the user opens the tab*" - seems you could do with being explicit in your requirement!

Comment: No, the rest are the conditions which could be so. The only thing is the page should be completely white, if the user is inactive for a long time. Also, the page should refresh automatically, if the user does some activity in that page

Comment: I had a hard time explaining that in the question itself

Comment: Not exactly related, but refreshing a page from time to time when user is interacting with the page is very poor UX. You can imagine how irritating it is, if you're ex. writing something into an input, and suddenly the page refreshes.

Comment: @Teemu The page must not refresh, if a user is interacting.